# RealmSwift + Application Entered Background

Tags: swift2, ios9, realm

Currently my app is trying to download a few json file, after each file is downloaded it writes to realm object, the process will take about a minute.

Bad news is when the user click on home button during this process, the app hangs upon returning back to foreground.

**Question: How do i keep the write transaction going on even when the app is in the background?**

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in development? Did you got any crash reports or do you see any error in the logs?

Comment: What are the NSFileProtection attributes of the main and auxiliary Realm files? Since Realm databases are files on disk, they're subject to the same system-level encryption access requirements as any other item on the file system. If NSFileProtectionComplete is set (which is the default in iOS 8+), those files won't be accessible when the device is locked. See Apple's guide for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Protection_Values

Comment: @jpsim thanks for the reply but i am quite new to swift programming so have no solid idea of what/where to check/do in regards to NSFileProtection.

How can i set them to NSFileProtectionNone so it will not hinder the Realm write transaction?

Comment: I encourage you to read the reference document I linked to. That should contain all the relevant information in much detail. You may also find this work-in-progress section of Realm's documentation useful: https://gist.github.com/jpsim/b976f546c5b4bf6231c3

Comment: @jpsim ok thnx alot! The explanation on the Realm's WIP documentation is helpful.

Comment: I've reposted these comments as an answer. Please consider accepting it if it helped you with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the NSFileProtection attributes of the main and auxiliary Realm files? Since Realm databases are files on disk, they're subject to the same system-level encryption access requirements as any other item on the file system. If NSFileProtectionComplete is set (which is the default in iOS 8+), those files won't be accessible when the device is locked. See Apple's guide for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Protection_Values

You may also find this work-in-progress section of Realm's documentation useful: https://gist.github.com/jpsim/b976f546c5b4bf6231c3